# How can I use an anti-derivative (integral) to find the velocity, given the acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

How can I write my acceleration as a function of time given its acceleration? Say a particle has an acceleration $a$ and an initial velocity $v_0$ at time $t = 0$. What is the particle's velocity at a later time $t$?

Please provide an answer which uses integration to find the velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think about what is the definition of an acceleration. The acceleration tells you how the velocity **changes** in time.

For example the gravitational acceleration at the surface of the earth is roughly $10 \frac{m}{s^2}$, which means if you begin to fall at time $t=0 s$, at $t=1 s$ you will have a velocity of $10\frac{m}{s^2}$, at $t=2s$ you will have a velocity of $20\frac{m}{s^2}$ and so on.

To be more precise mathematically, the acceleration is the derivative of the velocity, since it describes per definition the change in velocity. Of course if acceleration is the derivative of the velocity, then velocity is the antidervative of acceleration.

To write all down, the acceleration is defined as  $$a(t) = \frac{d v(t)}{dt}$$

which means that the velocity can be computed as $$v(t)=\int{a(t)dt}$$

For example if $$a(t) = 10$$ and the velocity at time $t = 0$ is $v_0$ then $$v(t) = \int{a(t) dt} = 10 \cdot t + C$$

Since $v(0) = C = v_0$ we get as final expression $$v(t) = 10t+v_0 $$